# I can't view "Reporting" in Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2017, reporting, toolbox

"Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm facing an issue with Visual Studio 2017 where the Reporting feature is not showing up in the Toolbox. I've tried to find solutions online, but haven't had any luck so far.

I'm specifically looking for guidance on how to display the Reporting feature in the Toolbox. Any help or insights on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

problem : I can't view "Peporting" in Toolbox